# Odd Checkbox Behaviour With Javascript / IE6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

This is the chain of events:

1) There is a visible HTML checkbox, the user checks or unchecks the box

2) The HTML checkbox is hidden via javascript by setting the display to none

3) The HTML checkbox is made visible via javascript by setting the display to block

4) The user's selection reverts to default value of the checkbox, for example, if the checkbox was first rendered with 'checked=checked', and the user unchecks the box, it goes back to being checked. If it was not rendered with checked, and the user checks the box, it does back to being unchecked.

The checkbox is hidden when the user opens up another part of my web app. But when they go back, the checkbox shouldn't have changed... stupid IE6... anyways to fix this?

I even tried adding a onclick function which effectively recreates a new checkbox object, destroys the odd and replaces it. This does not work either. Also, it doesn't work well since it doesn't stop this on behavior when there is no change on the checkbox.

Comment: Are you setting display:none on the checkbox element? Try setting it on its wrapper.

Comment: Nope, only onto the div container. Other than that no changes are being made to the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you writing to the `innerHTML` at any point in the script? For example, if you say `element.innerHTML+='x'` on an ancestor element, it will destroy and recreate the entire contents of the ancestor, which will lose non-HTML-serialisable content, including form field state.

Otherwise, just setting `display` on the checkbox should not affect its checkedness (and doesn't for me in IE6). However, setting the `display` directly to `block` is questionable as this is not the normal display value for a checkbox. To avoid having to worry about what the default checkbox display value is on various browsers, use CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

and toggle the checkbox between hidden and shown states by adding and removing the `className= 'hidden'`.

Comment: This sounds like what is happening, I am using FancyBox to create JavaScript light boxes, and it is when it switched between content light boxes when the issue occurs, and FancyBox probably makes some sort of innerHTML writing. Is there a solution? Besides from not using innerHTML since I would be using it for other functions than hiding content, such as adding / modifying content.

Comment: Is the checkbox actually inside fancybox content? Otherwise, as far as I can see, it shouldn't touch the `innerHTML`.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, but maybe display none resets the checkbox on IE6.

I have never tried it and I have no IE6 to test on.